# Unable to run on Ui thread- from Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to update my boolean flag from within the retrofit call method but the flag always returns false despite when flag executed as true from one block. Please let me know how to update the flag , what problem there is . how do i make use of courines in kotlin. please help me .

following below is my code

```
   fun checklogin(username: String,password: String):Boolean {

    Log.i("##check-coming here","ll")

    var  returningval=false

    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(AllConstants.MAIN_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
    val service =
        retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface::class.java)
    val call = service.login("oman123",username , password)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonObject> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<JsonObject>,
            response: Response<JsonObject>
        ) {
            try {

                if (response.code()==200)
                {
                    val obj = response.body()?.get("success")?.asJsonObject
                    jsonvalue=obj
                    returningval=true
                    Log.i("##check-coming here","rescode1"+returningval)
                }
                else if (response.code()==404)
                {
                   errorcode=404
                    returningval=false
                    Log.i("##check-coming here","rescode2"+returningval)
                }
                }
             catch (e: Exception) {
                 errorcode=505
                 returningval=false
                 Log.i("##check-coming here","rescode3"+returningval)
             }
        }

        override fun onFailure(
            call: Call<JsonObject>,
            t: Throwable
        ) {
            errorcode=606
            returningval=false
            Log.i("##check-coming here","rescode4"+returningval)
        }
    })

    return returningval
}
```

As above you can see the returningval flag that is always returning false despite if the statement is right , is it good way to use runonuithread or courines is best . please help me with code snippet please.

your help would be much appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: `runOnUiThread` probably won't be a good idea. If you use RxJava or Courontines, you could subscribe to response and actually `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulars.mainThread())`. I could add more code if you are interested.

Comment: call.enqueue is an async function so your method will return value without waiting for response. So in your case returningval is returned before you set value in it.

Comment: @MaryamMirzayee yes please . help me with the code for couroutines

Comment: @AmitTiwary he posted returningval in `onResponse` so it will be executed when call back has been recieved

Comment: @mdgouse this link explained it, however, you need to increase your level of abstraction.
https://android.jlelse.eu/implementing-rxjava2-retrofit2-for-better-performance-during-api-calls-fe1c53e1f939

Comment: What @AmitTiwary is saying is correct. use callbacks to get the proper response/result not the method return types in the case of async or different thread operations.

Comment: can it be achieved using couroutines??? as the return value is always been returned false though if it is true but still end value returned is false @MaryamMirzayee

Comment: @AmitTiwarywhat do you suggest now ? you are right in saying that my method is not waiting for the response , so it sends value before?

Comment: please help me out guys ... what shall i do now ?????

Comment: Yes it send value before. do you know rxjava? I can help with rxjava

Comment: no i dont know rxjava.. can it not be possible with couroutines?

Comment: yes, you can do it with coroutine also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with coroutine as shown below

```
suspend fun checklogin(username: String,password: String):Boolean{
      var  returningval=false

val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(AllConstants.MAIN_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build()
val service =
    retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface::class.java)
val response = service.login("oman123",username , password)
//hope response body is not null
if (response.isSuccessful) {
     returningval = true
}
return returningval
}
```

And login api

```
suspend fun login(parameters): Response<JsonObject>
```

Call checklogin function as

```
fun callCheckLogin(username: String,password: String){
  withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    val returningBool = checklogin(userName, password)
    //if want to use this val in main thread use withContext(Dispatchers.Main) below this line
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't run this code. If there is any syntax error please solve it.